# international characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, internationalization, character-encoding

I am working on a web application, where I transfer data from the server to the browser in XML.

Since I'm danish, I quickly run into problems with the characters `æøå`.

I know that in html, I use the `"&amp;aelig;&amp;oslash;&amp;aring;"` for `æøå`.

however, as soon as the chars pass through JavaScript, I get black boxes with `"?"` in them when using `æøå`, and `"&aelig;&oslash;&aring;"` is printed as is.

I've made sure to set it to utf-8, but that isn't helping much.

Ideally, I want it to work with any special characters (naturally).

The example that isn't working is included below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            alert("&aelig;&oslash;&aring;");
            alert("æøå");

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Ok, thanks to Grapefrukts answer, I got it working.

I actually needed it for data coming from an MySQL server. Since the saving of the files in UTF-8 encoding only solves the problem for static content, I figure I'd include the solution for strings from a MySQL server, pulled out using PHP:

`utf8_encode($MyStringHere)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just specifying UTF-8 in the header is not enough. I'd bet you haven't saved your file as UTF-8. Any reasonably advanced text editor will have this option. Try that and I'm sure it'll work!

Answer (score 24):

If you ever can't set the response encoding, you can use `\u` escape sequence in the JavaScript string literal to display these characters.

```
alert("\u00e6\u00f8\u00e5")
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `String.fromCharCode()` to output a character from a numeric entity.

e.g. `String.fromCharCode( 8226 )` will create a bullet character.

Answer (score 1):

I get "&aelig;&oslash;&aring;" for the first one and some junk characters for the next. Could it be that the javascript is not mangling (or [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)) your letters but the alert dialog uses the system default font, and the font is incapable of displaying the letters?

Answer (score 1):

I use the code like this with Thai language.  It's fine.

`$message` is my PHP variable.

```
echo("<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'></head><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('" . $message . "');</script></body></html>");
```

Hope this can help.  Thank you.

(I cannot post image of what I did as the system said "I don't have enough reputation", so I leave the image, here. http://goo.gl/9P3DtI Sorry for inconvenience.)

Sorry for my weak English.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for me:

```
alert("&aelig;&oslash;&aring;");
```

... creates an alert containing the string "&aelig;&oslash;&aring;" whereas

```
alert("æøå");
```

... creates an alert with the non-ascii characters.

Javascript is pretty utf-8 clean and doesn't tend to put obstacles in your way.

Maybe you're putting this on a web server that serves it as ISO-8859-1? If you use Apache, in your Apache config file (or in .httaccess, if you can override), you should have a line

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
```

(Note: edited to escape the ampersands... otherwise it didn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` method won't decode UTF-8 encoded characters sent by AJAX requests, at least not when the webpage uses a non-UTF-8 encoding (such as ISO-8859-1).

Workaround (uses jQuery):

```js
var msg = 'This is a bull &bull; and this is a star &#9733;';
var msgu = $('<span/>').html(msg).text();
alert(msgu);
```

This works for all &xxx characters that the browser can display because the `innerHTML()` method (or `html()` in jQuery's case) creates an UTF-8 valid string.