# how show persian characters in alert box?

Tags: javascript, php, unicode, encoding, persian

i have set utf-8 as my encoding both in html and my php header and everything is ok when i run on localhost but when i upload my file on my host everything is ok but alert and confirm box that opens by javascript, they are encode by unicode like \u60A5 
i don't know what should i do
i have tried these:
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
and also

---

i have tried this and seems to work fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

alert("\u062A\u0633\u062A \u0641\u0627\u0631\u0633\u06CC");

Comment: i have also set <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: This is a duplicate question that looks like can be [answered here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825/international-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: i don't retrieve my string from any other page, i just write my persian string but get \u escape sequence of it.

Comment: Show a piece of code that actually reproduces the issue. Preferably, also put it in a jsfiddle and share the address. \u60A5 denotes a Chinese character, so something odd is going on. This may relate to character encodings, so we we may need to see the actual HTTP headers too.

Comment: What is the code that does *not* work? And what is that actually appears in the alert or confirm box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure this is in your apache config:

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
```