# UTF-8 characters in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using `datapicker` but the utf8 characters are displaying wrong in my html like `DÃ©CEMBRE` or `AOÃ»T` . All my files (.jsp & .js) are saved as utf-8.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
 //...
 monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 
              'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembreé', 'Décembre'],
 //...
});
```

Also i set this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/calendar.js"  charset="UTF-8"></script>           
    <script  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/datepicker.js"  charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure you have: `<meta charset="utf-8">` just below `<head>`

Comment: yes of course i have it.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem and The solution was weird because after doing all the possible solution as Xavier propose

> Here are different thinks to think about:
>   [international characters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825/international-characters-in-javascript) in short: Meta must have UTF8,
>   files must be saved as UTF8(important!) and your Webserver may need to
>   have UTF8

The problem was not fixed so I make a `clean..` and `clean Tomcat Work Directory` in my tomcat server and I restart it. I refresh the page In chrome but I still got wrong character

So I try with Mozilla and the problem was finally solved also i open a new window in Chrome using ctrl+shift+n. This will open a new incognito window and the character display good.

So for normal chrome it works after i closed the tab and i open it again.

So i think it's a cache problem in `apache tomcat` or in browsers cache so to avoid this problem you have to try all this solution ;)

Comment: Try opening a new window in Chrome using `ctrl`+`shift`+`n`. This will open a new incognito window that is not affected by client side caching.

Comment: yes i try it and now the problem is solved even with normal chrome as i describe in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting UTF-8 in your script tag 
example:

```
<script src="/explorer/html/js/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

I'm using boostrap datepicker and all works fine.

Comment: where do you set monthNames? I suppose in calendar.js. what datepicker are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest possible way to get rid of this issue is to use the HTML representation of your special characters

For example for é use `&eacute;`

So it will be `'F&eacute;rier'`

See http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm for a list of the available codes

Comment: yes it's working solution i try already but if my all character was in Arabic it will not solve my problem.

Comment: Here are different thinks to think about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825/international-characters-in-javascript in short: Meta must have UTF8, files must be saved as UTF8(important!) and your Webserver may need to have UTF8

Comment: yes that normally but this time something is missing with me !!

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to ensure that the locale file was saved as UTF-8 instead of ANSI.  I didn't seem to need charset attributes on script tags or a meta tag indicating that (at least in Chrome).